# Autofac inject singleton for SQLiteAsyncConnection with params

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, dependency-injection

I m doing a Xamarin Native project with a PCL, I have a first class that is used to define the location of the database for each plateform :

```
  public class DatabaseConfiguration : IDatabaseConfiguration
    {
        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            //This code is specific to each platform
            return PathForEachPlatform;
        }
    }
```

I inject it like this :

```
  builder.RegisterType<DatabaseConfiguration>()
                    .As<IDatabaseConfiguration>()
                    .SingleInstance();
```

Now I wan't to inject the `SQLiteAsyncConnection` into my repository class. This class is from this nugets : https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl

Here is my repository constructor :

```
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection Connection { get; }

            public SQLiteRepository(IDatabaseConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString()); // I wan't to inject the connection not create a new one.
            }
}
```

`SQLiteAsyncConnection` does not provide an interface, so I decide to use a singleton. But the constructor need a database path. This path is define by the other injection above with the `GetConnectionString()` method. How can I do that ?

For now I have this code :

```
 builder.RegisterInstance<SQLiteAsyncConnection>()
        .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string),"HERE THE PATH TO PASS BUT HOW ?"))
        .SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
builder.Register
    (c => new SQLiteAsyncConnection(
        c.Resolve<IDatabaseConfiguration>().GetConnectionString()))
    .SingleInstance();
```

This will allow you to register the connection and also inject in the necessary connection string.

Comment: Why do you delete the .As<SQLiteAsyncConnection>() ? it loks good for me no ?

Comment: It is optional, it doesn't need to be there. You can leave it there if you like - it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: OK, tha't working, I will do some more checks and validate the answer thanks a lot my friend !